# error updating data in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the data in mongodb as:

```
{
  "_id":ObjectId("5415dsc5fdvfv15vff65"),
  "username":"myusername",
  "friends": [
     {
     "name":"friend1",
     "isFriend":false
     },
     {
     "name":"friend2",
     "isFriend":false
     }
  ]       
}
```

Now I am trying to update my 'isFriend' status to 'true'.

my nodejs code for updation is:

```
User.update({username:'myUsername',friends.name:'friend1'},{$set:{friends:{name:'friend1',isFriend:true}}}, function(err,val){
 console.log(val.nModified);
});
```

But this code shows an error **Unexpected token .** **in friends.name**

How do we do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
User.update({username:'myUsername','friends.name':'friend1'},{$set:{ "friends.$.name" : "updated name","friends.$.isFriend":true }}, function(err,val){
 console.log(val.nModified);
});
```

Comment: it gives the ouput   {ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }, so the modification is not successful

Comment: it must be work if your `username` and `friends.name` values matches in `query` parameter.
Check proper your both values.

Comment: yeah, i was making a mistake, Thanks. I have another query: how to add 'friend3' if 'friend3' does not exist in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Nested criteria should be string

```
User.update({username:'myUsername','friends.name':'friend1'},{$set:{'friends.$.isFriend': true}}, function(err,val){
 console.log(val.nModified);
});
```

Comment: now the error is not showing, but the the data is also not getting updated. The value of val.nModified is 0.

Comment: @Krisalay The update part should be fixed. Another answer gives the right one. So I don't update mine.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough add double quotes "friends.name"

Comment: now the error is not showing, but the the data is also not getting updated. The value of val.nModified is 0.